# Sharepoint with ASP.NET Ajax

Tags: ajax, sharepoint, moss, scriptmanager

I'm running a MOSS2007 Sharepoint website with .NET 3.5 Ajax. I'm using the SmartPart webpart to host a user control that contains an update panel.

I've added the script manager to the /_catalogs/masterpage/default.master file and it works fine when I log in as myself. But when I log in as a normal user I get the error message `The control with ID 'UpdatePanel1' requires a ScriptManager on the page`.

As far as I can tell, it's loading a different version of the masterpage for the different users (a user control with `this.Page.MasterPageFile` consistently returns /_catalogs/masterpage/default.master) but other edits I've made as tests don't show either...

Is there's any way to easily add a script manager to all master pages for all users (I'd rather have it on a page and not used, than needed on a page and not there)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My stupid mistake. Needed to approve the new master page version after checking it in.